# How to write a xpath to match all elements except a particular element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am writing an XSL transformation. I want to write a template which matches all the child elements of the document except one particular node. My xml looks like this -

```
<Document>
    <NodeA></NodeA>

    <NodeB></NodeB>

    <ServiceNode></ServiceNode>

    <NodeX></NodeX>
</Document>
```

I want to write a template that matches all nodes except `ServiceNode` i.e. `NodeA` to `NodeX`. How to write this Xpath to get -

```
<xsl:template match="ALL Nodex Except ServiceNode">
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for four alternative solutions for four different possible meanings of this question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I want to write a template that
>   matches all nodes except ServiceNode
>   i.e. NodeA to NodeX.

**If by "node" you mean element, then use**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::ServiceNode)]">
```

**If by "node" you mean any node (of type element, text, comment, processing-instruction): use**

```
<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::ServiceNode)]">
```

**If you want only children of `Document` to be matched use:**

```
<xsl:template match="Document/node()[not(self::ServiceNode)]">
```

**If you want only children of the top element to be matched use:**

```
<xsl:template match="/*/node()[not(self::ServiceNode)]">
```

Answer (score 7):

You should better use this expression:

```
*[not(self::ServiceNode)]
```

As incorporated in an XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ServiceNode)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XML sample:

```
<Document>
    <NodeA>1</NodeA>
    <NodeB>2</NodeB>
    <ServiceNode>3</ServiceNode>
    <NodeX>4</NodeX>
</Document>
```

It will give a correct result:

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: Correct. This is better than testing on name() or local-name(). In XPath 2.0 an alternative is (* except ServiceNode)

Comment: I agree. Better than `name()`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<xsl:template match="Document/*[name() != 'ServiceNode']">
```

(or `local-name()` if you have to deal with namespaces)

Comment: I recommend testing in a live evaluator like http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm where you can paste expressions like //*[name()!="pet"]

Answer (score 3):

You could use two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="Document/*">
   ...do something...
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Document/ServiceNode" />
```

The later template will take priority, so the first template will match everything except ServiceNode.

Comment: This could be useful in some cases, besides it doesn't answer this question properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Document/*[not(name()='ServiceNode')]
```